# NetSuite - using nlapiCopyRecord function

Tags: netsuite, suitescript

I am generating an invoice when the original invoice is overdue by a certain time period. I want to know if we can use the nlapiCopyRecord to make a copy of the original invoice but allow us to insert a new line that will replace the old line item? I haven't found any sample to show how this is done.

Thanks.

Edit 1:

```
            var new_inv = nlapiCopyRecord('invoice', internal_id,
        {
            item : 66,
            amount: amount,
            description: 'TEST'

        });
        var copiedId = nlapiSubmitRecord(new_inv);
        return copiedId;
```

Above code fails in my scheduled script. **You have entered an invalid default value for this record initialize operation**.

I would like to override the line item on the newly copied invoice

Answer (score 1):

Yes that is possible, just like if you copy a record in the UI you can modify the copy. You also need to remember that you need to save the record object after you have copied it.

Comment: Thanks. How do we create / override the existing line item?

Answer (score 1):

Why are you doing this? If you are trying to charge a late fee you'd probably be better off by adding an expense line to the original invoice record. If you don't have expenses turned on then you could add an other "Other Charge for Sale"

If your code is running server side then:

```
var invRec = nlapiLoadRecord('invoice', internal_id);
var chargeIndex = invRec.getLineItemCount('item') + 1;
// don't think you need this for the end position invRec.insertLineItem('item', chargeIndex);
invRec.setLineItemValue('item', 'item', chargeIndex, charge_item_id);
invRec.setLineItemValue('item', 'rate', chargeIndex, amount);
invRec.setLineItemValue('item', 'amount', chargeIndex, amount);
nlapiSubmitRecord(invRec);
```

OR if you use an expense

```
var invRec = nlapiLoadRecord('invoice', internal_id);
invRec.insertLineItem('expense', 1);
invRec.setLineItemValue('expense', 'account', 1, penalty_account);
invRec.setLineItemValue('expense', 'amount', 1, amount);
invRec.setLineItemValue('expense', 'memo', 1, 'TEST');
nlapiSubmitRecord(invRec);
```

Comment: Hey - thanks for that. So the idea is that we'd run a scheduled script and identify which invoice has been overdue for an x amount of time. Based on this we'd create a penalty fee invoice which we'd send to clients. This is part of the contract. So I figured the best way would be to clone the invoice and simply override the line item with the new late fee line item.

Comment: As long as you're not overwriting a line from the originating Sales Order you can just tag the late fees onto the original Invoice. IMO it keeps things cleaner